# Urinating while excreting

Tags: urinary-system, stools, urination, urethra, defecation

Can passing faeces and urinating occur at the same moment and if not, why?

Now I don't have any medical knowledge really or background but the only conclusion I can come to is that faeces press against the connection internally from the bladder to the urethra preventing urine being released until the pressure is removed from the connection.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. I have allowed myself to propose an edit to your question to make it more adhering to site rules and to remove irrelevant detail (we are not a forum). Feel free to accept that edit or [edit] the question yourself.

Comment: I've always been curious about this as well

Answer (score 1):

There are voluntary and involuntary muscles on urination.  The default circuit is to close the involuntary during and before bowel. It is a way of the body forcing you to clear the bowel.

[urination](https://www.britannica.com/science/urination)

Comment: Please include references.

Answer (score 0):

They certainly can occur at the same moment, but there are also situations where they might not. Similar to your hypothesis, if someone is for example severely constipated they may not be able to urinate until they have had a bowel movement due to the urethra (the tube that allows urine to leave your bladder) being pinched off from the pressure of the stool.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].